# Specifying audio bitrate of MP3 does not work as expected

Tags: mp3, bitrate

I converted bitrate of audio file using `ffmpeg` which I built by myself.
But option `-b:a 32k` will create actually 96kbps file.
Are there any precautions when building?

I built ffmpeg with the next configuration:

```
./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared  --enable-libmp3lame
```

And I converted audio by the next command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Sample.m4a -b:a 32k Out.mp3
```

Comment: Ffmpeg's bug ?  
But executables built by gyan.dev and BtbN work OK.  
Why ?